# Addressing "Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor"

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two DB clsses, one copies the db file from assets to the phone.

the Second is where I have been putting my DB calls but in the log I am getting an awrful lot error about I should close the cursor. This I am getting confused about as all my calls have a cursor.close() on the end.

Code of second:

```
public class DatabaseTools extends Common {


    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public DatabaseTools(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //  MARKS
    public ArrayList<String> getNames(String value) {
                Names = new ArrayList<String>();

                selectStatement = new String[] { DB_COMMON_COL_NAME };
                fromStatement = DB_COMMON_COL_VALUE + " = '" + value + "'";

            cursor = db.query(
                DB_DISTANCE_TABLE_NAME, 
                selectStatement, 
                fromStatement, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);

        int distanceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COMMON_COL_NAME);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {                
                distanceNames.add(cursor.getString(distanceIndex));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

        return names;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification to ensure you close your cursor. Also you're getting database instance in your constructor. That's not good. You should get database instance right before you work with the database, and call close() on the database, as soon as you're finished. I would suggest moving db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() inside the getNames(String value) method, than calling db.close() when you're done - also in finally block.

```
    public ArrayList<String> getNames(String value) {
            Names = new ArrayList<String>();

            selectStatement = new String[] { DB_COMMON_COL_NAME };
            fromStatement = DB_COMMON_COL_VALUE + " = '" + value + "'";

            cursor = db.query(
            DB_DISTANCE_TABLE_NAME, 
            selectStatement, 
            fromStatement, 
            null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

              try {
                  int distanceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB_COMMON_COL_NAME);
                  while(cursor.moveToNext()) { 
                     distanceNames.add(cursor.getString(distanceIndex));            
                  }
              } finally { 
                if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
              }
            }

        return names;

     }
```